# How can I create an RSS feed that includes "Private" posts?

Tags: posts, rss, private

I'm currently publishing articles to wordpress as "Private", as I don't want them to be viewable on the website. However I do need an RSS feed of these posts. Any suggestions on how to go about creating an RSS feed of posts that aren't viewable on my site?

Answer (score 1):

I assume your theme already has a 'feed-rss.php' (if not, here's how they work: http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_Feeds)

You'll need to pass a few parameters to the query before you loop through them.

```
//Get all posts that are private or public
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_status' => array( 'private', 'publish' ) );
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    //do stuff
}
```

For more parameters: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Status_Parameters

Comment: Hmm... I wonder if there is a nicer way to do this with this http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_Feeds#Customizing_Feed_Templates

Comment: Where should that code be inserted? I set up a custom feed template which is working. However when I insert your code into the feed template I get a 500 error. (Also, your code is missing a close parentheses).